# Carto Builder: No geo reference

Tags: carto

I'm pretty new with Carto. I have worked with Carto Editor one time in the past, but in Carto Builder I'm missing the "Merge -> column join" option.

I tried to create a map by using the two data sets I have (geodata from my city in Germany) and a dataset with statistics structured by zip codes. I marked both datasets and clicked on "create map". But somehow carto tells me, the dataset with the statistics has no geo reference.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

In CARTO Builder, table joins (as well as most data manipulation) is done through *Analysis*. You just have to follow these steps:

1. Import **both** datasets to your map. Remember you'll have to do import each dataset one by one! As you pointed out, only one of those has a valid geometry; the *statistics* dataset will display a yellow warning triangle, meaning it has no geometry and can't be plotted on the map.
2. Click on your dataset that **does** have a geometry column in it and switch to the ANALYSIS tab.
3. Click ADD ANALYSIS, then select the *Join columns from second layer* option.
4. Now fill in the wizard with (2) the dataset you mean to join, (3) the columns that match in both datasets, normally a name or code, and (4) the rows you want to keep from each table. When in doubt, just selct all columns from both tables.
5. Click APPLY... and you're done!

You can find this and more info about CARTO Builder in the [CARTO Guides](https://carto.com/learn/guides)...

...and see the whole process in action in the following GIF:

[image: Inner Join GIF]

**Disclaimer:** I'm currently working for CARTO's Support Team.

Comment: Hey arredond! Thank you for your help. I'm still failing at point 3 (foreign keys) - What do I have to enter into these fields? Thank you so much, you've been a huge help!!!

Comment: In order for a JOIN to work, you need to link both datasets through a common field. For example, if your layer with geodata from your city is structured in post codes, and you have a postcode field, you'd have to select the postcode field in both datasets. You can learn more about SQL Joins here: http://www.sql-join.com/

Answer (score 0):

The join is still in there! (Just no so obvious;-))

First you have to create a map with your geodata. Within this map you have to add an analysis. The analysis you are looking for is "Join Columns from 2nd layer"